# Why is the dropdown menu displaying without hovering over the main menu itself?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

For this site http://www.baptisteyoga.com/

If I move the cursor a bit below the main menu, the dropdown menu displays. Why? It's a bit annoying/unnecessary. What we want is for the submenu to only appear when we hover over the main nav menu itself. e.g. **only** hovering over "Programs" shows the dropdown menu for Programs.

Basically for the standard menu behaviour to apply.

Anyone know?
Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: I think it would be easier to not use to many nestled css rules. You have `header .large-menu nav > ul > li:hover > a`. Try just making a class for the element which should trigger the hover motion and apply the css for that class instead. I'm not saying that this is the solution, but its the best I can think of without knowing more.

Comment: here `header .large-menu .has-dropdown .sub-menu {opacity: 0;}` it makes element invisble but it covers the space so on mouse hover it shows

Comment: Hi @Shehary that seems to be it. I'm just not sure how to refactor it for it to work?

Comment: @magician11, you resolved the problem or still struggling with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason drop-down menu shows even mouse not on menu because following CSS selector has `opacity: 0;` and on hover `opacity: 1;`, there is no problem with the approach but opacity doesn't hide the element just make it transparent so it is there but not visible

```
header .large-menu .has-dropdown .sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -90px;
    top: 50px;
    height: 0;
    width: 180px;
    opacity: 0; <<<---Here
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
}

header .large-menu .has-dropdown:hover .sub-menu {
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1; <<<---Here
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
}
```

So better approach is to hide the element change `opacity` property to `visibility` property as like below

```
header .large-menu .has-dropdown .sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -90px;
    top: 50px;
    height: 0;
    width: 180px;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
}

header .large-menu .has-dropdown:hover .sub-menu {
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Shehary. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have given the hover property to anchor tag. The complete area of  tag will cover the functionality.

Limit the height and width of the particular tag to just the text.

If you modify the height property available in the following CSS will work:

**header .large-menu nav > ul > li > a**

NOTE: Please make sure this height change does not have impact on other components using the same class hierarchy.

Comment: mm.. I edited the height and the line-height property and it didn't seem to make any difference?